Reply to Gmail email
When I receive emails they are at the top of the screen.  When I reply it's at the bottom.  I know you can click on the 3 dots to get the whole conversation, but can you reply to the emails at the very top of the screen, right above the message you are replying to?

Common complain about conversation view in Gmail. You could switch it off, switch to a different mail client, or try one of the Chrome extensions that claims to solve it but if you look at the comments on them as many people say they work as say they don't in some way. Maybe just try a few.
